# How to solve problem when Java Bean mapper has different source and dest field in payload?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, mapping, javabeans

I have  Company entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "company_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int companyId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 255, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Employee> employeeList;
}
```

And Employee entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int employeeId;

    @Column(name = "employee_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;
}
```

I have trouble when I'm mapping `EmployeeRequest` to `Employee` object.
This is `EmployeeRequest`:

```java
@Data
public class EmployeeRequest {
    private String name;
    private int companyId;
}
```

As you can see here in request I have `companyId` which is integer and therefore I have error.
My mapper:

```java
@Component
public class EmployeeMapper {
    private Mapper mapper = DozerBeanMapperBuilder.buildDefault();

     public Employee transformToEmployeeEntity(EmployeeRequest employeeRequest) {
        return mapper.map(employeeRequest, Employee.class);
    }
}
```

I think it makes sense to have an integer as data type in `EmployeeRequest`. So what is proper way to solve this?

Comment: Which Mapper are you using? Nevertheless, that is why I usually prefer to do the mapping on my own instead of relying on a 3rd party library.

Comment: @JoãoDias I'm using Dozer Mapper. I also prefer to use my own, but in this case i have to use Dozer. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've never used or even known Dozer.